# Apache Load Balancer: Forward request to multiple balancer members

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, request

I got a Apache Load Balancer with two balancer members. When a specific request is sent to the Apache Server (for example "localhost:80/replace") I want to forward this request to all balancer members. How can I do this? Do I need mod_perl for this?